# MariaDB 10.5 changing sql_mode in .cnf does not change @@sql_mode, why?

Tags: mariadb, my.cnf, sql-mode, mariadb-10.5

Fedora Desktop 35 running MariaDB 10.5, completely fresh install from about a month ago.

Why is my change to `/etc/my.cnf/mariadb-server.cnf` `sql_mode` changing `@@GLOBAL.sql_mode` but not `@@sql_mode`?

I'm trying to remove `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` from my `sql_mode` (I have a column that is DATETIME NOT NULL that I need to omit from an INSERT and have it assume a default value).  My system has a simple MariaDB installation with a nearly empty `/etc/my.cnf` that includes all files in `/etc/my.cnf.d` where there is a `mariadb-server.cnf` with a `[server]` section where I can set `sql-mode`.

If omitted, it defaults as specified in https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/sql_mode/ to `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`.  Confirmed by querying via SquirrelSQL:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@sql_mode;
global  @@sql_mode
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION   STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

So by default both `@@sql_mode` and `@@GLOBAL.sql_mode` are equivalent.

Adding this to `mariadb-server.cnf` (`[server]` line was already there):

```
[server]
sql_mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Restart server with `systemctl restart mariadb`, no errors in journal, and re-run the query from above:

```
global  @@sql_mode
ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION   STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Note that the global `sql_mode` no longer has `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, but the non-global one does! Why, and what can I do about it?

The insert still fails due to the strict rule being in effect.